# Where do I modify the CUPS printer configuration?

Tags: networking, printing

Our systems people want us to configure the network printers via CUPS. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I cannot see how to set up the printers in the graphical menu.

The instructions I got are the following:

```
Edit cupsd.conf (probably in /etc/cups but varies by distribution) to contain 
the lines: 

 BrowsePoll printhost01.myorg.ac.uk
 BrowsePoll printhost02.myorg.ac.uk
```

Where should I do this in my Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: You can easily configure with web interface. Here is tutorial: [http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/05/seprinters-linux.html][1]
[1]: http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/05/seprinters-linux.html
Every Linux machine with CUPS installed have web interface for printers. Enter for example: `http://192.168.1.4:631/printers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cupsd.conf should be in `/etc/cups` for Ubuntu. If not, just create the file.

From the terminal, type

```
sudo nano /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
```

and then copy paste the above lines

Comment: Thanks I got it working, although sometimes it takes a while to print something on the network printer, but it may be that the cups server is busy.